# Unable to view the download PDF file in browser in php

Tags: php, joomla

I have a download media function in which all type of media files gets downloaded. Below is the code

```
public function downloadMedia($file, $filename_direct = '', $extern = '', $exitHere = 1)
    {
        jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');

        clearstatcache();

        if (!$extern)
        {
            if (!JFile::exists($file))
            {
                return 2;
            }
            else
            {
                $len = filesize($file);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* Return the size of a remote url or a local file specified by $url.
                $thereturn specifies the unit returned (either bytes "", MiB "mb" or KiB
                "kb"). */
            $len = filesize($file);
        }

        $filename       = basename($file);

        $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename, "."), 1));
        $ctype = $this->getMime($file_extension);

        ob_end_clean();

        //  Needed for MS IE - otherwise content disposition is not used?
        if (ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
        {
            ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
        }

        header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate");
        header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0');
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Type: " . $ctype);
        header("Content-Length: " . (string) $len);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');

        //  set_time_limit doesn't work in safe mode
        if (!ini_get('safe_mode'))
        {
            @set_time_limit(0);
        }

        /*@readfile($file);

        if ($exitHere == 1)
        {
            exit;
        }*/

        $fp = fopen($file, "r") ;

        ob_clean();
        flush();
        while (!@feof($fp)) {
            $buff = @fread($fp, $len);
            print $buff;
        }

        exit;
    }
```

Now the issue is, whenever I download the PDF file & clicked on downloaded file it shows an error in a browser like 'Failed to load PDF document.'

[image: Error Image]

The downloaded PDF file is opened correctly only when if I open the file in adobe instead of opening it in browser.

Comment: Why do you hide errors ?

Comment: Try opening the downloaded file in a text editor.

Comment: @JonStirling End user will not open the downloaded file into the text editor. Whenever file get downloaded & user clicks on that file then a file is automatically opened into browser & then it displays this error.

Comment: @executable which errors? @readfile?? even if I remove the '@' it gives the same error while opening the file in a browser.

Comment: actually it's a browser version issue. For chrome version 70, 71 it works but does not support lower version.

Comment: anybody suggest any solution as it should work for all browsers & versions.

Comment: The problem is the readfile part. That doesn’t do a really good job for larger/some PDF files. I don’t know exactly what goes wrong, maybe when I have time I will try to figure that out but for now I will just present you a solution that worked for me:

Comment: commented readfile code in a question & added new solution

Comment: "Solutions" on Stackoverflow are to be posted as "Answers".

Comment: Did you try `echo file_get_contents($file);`?  Do you know about http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php ? It looks like your `if-else` block could be optimized. The `@` (stfu operator) should generally be avoided.  The warnings that it silences actually assist you in dealing with conflicts that arise.